In the Silmarillion or the Appendices to ROTK, do the Dwarves of Khazad-dûm know about the Balrog below prior to Durin receiving the ring?
We know from the Silmarillion that after the War of Wrath, the few surviving Balrogs went deep underground and hid. Durin's Bane burrowed deep underground the Dwarven city of Khazad-dûm and slumbered.
I am making the assumption that this occurred before Khazad-dûm was founded. (I could be wrong.) It seems to me that the Dwarves then un-knowingly (or knowingly) built the city of Khazad-dûm on top of the Balrog because of the mineral supplies and that it was a good mountain in which to build a city. (It seems perhaps the Elves and Wizards could have known, and perhaps may have told the Dwarves at some point in time.)
My question is about how much the Dwarves knew about the Balrog at the time that Durin received his ring.
In the television depiction "Rings of Power" based loosely on the Appendices to ROTK in s2e7 we see a Dwarf say "He'll awaken that beast down below." Which implies that the Dwarves did know about the Balrog, and considered living in the city acceptable, provided they managed the risks appropriately.
My question is: In the Silmarillion or the Appendices to ROTK, do the Dwarves of Khazad-dûm know about the Balrog below prior to Durin receiving the ring?


My understanding has been they didn't know until they woke it up. Moria was there before the second age, IIRC. Balrog came later.

"based loosely on the Appendices to ROTK". The word "loosely" is doing a lot of work here.

Would you move into a house if you knew there was a Balrog sleeping in the basement?

@SimonCrase Think of the business opportunities!  Sell tickets to see the sleeping Balrog! Sell Balrog merch! Open private research institute to study Balrogs, and take all those sweet government contracts!

Concerning the quote from the TV series, note that it's shown in previous episodes that Durin IV's wife Disa encounters a betentacled monster in a pond in the mines, and feels "something evil" that scares her, and which causes her to vocally oppose further digging. This is clearly what the quote is referring to, and it's a recent, unsubstantiated and unspecific warning. They definitely do not know there's a Balrog.

I interpreted "that beast down below" to refer to what Disa encountered an episode or two before (when she chased the geode sphere down to some body of water). Remember she and her kind sense things in the stone of the mountain: she knows something big and nasty is down there, but she does not know a Balrog is down there. Presumably Disa shared details of her encounter with others.

There is no indication the Dwarves (or anyone else, for that matter) had any idea there was a Balrog below Moria.
Khazad-dûm was founded long before the Balrog came to rest there, during the First Age. Durin I was the eldest of the Seven Fathers of the Dwarves (LotR III Appendix A Part III), created by Aulë before even the Elves (Silmarillion Chapter 2) but laid to rest in Middle Earth until after the Firstborn race had come forth. The appendix tells how "in the deeps of time", after he was awakened, he came to the caves in the east of the Misty Mountains above the Mirrowmere, and made his dwelling there, which became Moria in later times. He lived there for so long that he was known as the Deathless, yet still died before the end of the First Age - so Khazad-dûm must have stood for a very long time before the War of Wrath.
During the War of Wrath, most of the Balrogs were destroyed, and the rest fled. This is the event that marks the end of the First Age. "The Balrogs were destroyed, save some few that fled and hid themselves in caverns inaccessible at the roots of the earth" (Silmarillion Chapter 24). The Balrog that later became Durin's Bane hid himself deep under Caradhras at this time; but in an "inaccessible" cavern, not one connected to Khazad-dûm. It slumbered throughout the whole of the Second Age, and nearly two thousand years of the Third Age before being awoken in 1980 TA.
The Rings of Power were forged from circa 1500 of the Second Age (LotR III Appendix B). Appendix A tells us that during the Second Age "the power and wealth of Khazad-dûm was much increased". The Dwarves held (Appendix A) that Durin's Ring was the first of the Seven to be forged, and given to Durin III by the Elven-smiths, not Sauron, so we could say that he received it at the earliest in 1500. So, did the Dwarves know a Balrog was hidden below Khazad-dûm in 1500? That would be around 1500 years after it first buried itself there. It seems very unlikely. Khazad-dûm is experiencing a golden age during the start of the Second Age at this time; we hear (Appendix B) "Many Dwarves leaving their old cities in Ered Luin go to Moria and swell its numbers." And the Dwarves are building a strong friendship with the nearby Elves - "the friendship that grew up between the people of Durin and the Elven-smiths of Eregion was the closest that there has ever been between the two races." If any of them knew that a Balrog was sleeping underfoot, it seems they would have done what they could to drive it out, or at least not emigrated into Moria in such numbers. The Balrog was fleeing the destruction of its race; it would have chosen the deepest and most inaccessible hiding place it could to try and save itself. Had the forces of the Valar known where the Balrogs were hiding after the War of Wrath they would have continued their rout and destroyed them.
In 1980 of the Third Age, the dwarves of Khazad-dûm "delved too greedily and too deep" (LotR I, "A Journey in the Dark") searching for mithril below Caradhras, and awaken (or release from prison - the Appendix offers that it might already have been awake thanks to Sauron's growing power, but unable to get out) the Balrog. It seems they are taken totally unawares by this (or they would have been much more careful about where they were mining). Appendix A notes "Thus they roused from sleep a thing of terror that, flying from Thangorodrim, had lain hidden at the foundation of the earth since the coming of the Host of the West". Lain "hidden" - i.e., no one knew it was there.

Nice, but I don't think the balrog "slumbered". There could be lots of things to do in the basement of the world.

No
Khazad-dûm Was there before the Balrog as it was established by Durin early in the First Age; long before the War of Wrath and the subsequent flight of the balrog. We can assume that the Balrog did not come in through one of the doors.
The Silmarillion makes no mention of what happened to the balrogs - the entire War of Wrath is less than 2 pages.
Appendix A says:

It came to pass that in the middle of the Third Age Durin was again its king, being the sixth of that name. The power of Sauron, servant of Morgoth, was then again growing in the world, though the Shadow in the Forest that looked towards Moria was not yet known for what it was. All evil things were stirring. The Dwarves delved deep at that time, seeking beneath Barazinbar for mithril,  the metal beyond price that was becoming yearly ever harder to win. Thus they roused from sleep [footnote: Or released from prison, it may well be that it had already been awakened by the malice of Sauron] a thing of terror that, flying from Thangorodrim, had lain hidden at the foundations of the earth since the coming of the Host of the West: a Balrog of Morgoth. Durin was slain by it, and the year after Nain I, his son; and then the glory of Moria passed, and its people were destroyed or fled far away

Appendix B says:

1980 A Balrog appears in Moria, and slays Durin VI.
1981 Nain I slain. The Dwarves flee from Moria.

And that’s it.
So, no, the Dwarves did not know. Most likely nobody knew.
Furthermore, even after the Dwarves fled, it’s likely nobody knew that Durin’s Bane was a balrog. See When does Gandalf learn the nature of Durin’s Bane?
